# URL changes after the site opens

Tags: flutter

On a website/web app developed in Flutter I have a redirect from the "normal" URL to the firestore address.

I would like to keep the URL [www.thatexoticbug.com.br](http://www.thatexoticbug.com.br) and prevent it from being changed to thatexoticbug.web.app

[Before press enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxsyD.png)

[When loads the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBBrd.png)

I tried using the URL Strategy below, but I only managed to stop the page names from appearing during navigation, which was a huge win.

```
class XDPathUrlStrategy extends HashUrlStrategy {
  // Creates an instance of [PathUrlStrategy].
  // The [PlatformLocation] parameter is useful for testing to mock out browser interactions.
  XDPathUrlStrategy([
    super.platformLocation,
  ]) : _basePath = stripTrailingSlash(extractPathname(checkBaseHref(
          platformLocation.getBaseHref(),
        )));

  final String _basePath;

  @override
  String prepareExternalUrl(String internalUrl) {
    if (internalUrl.isNotEmpty && !internalUrl.startsWith('/')) {
      internalUrl = '/$internalUrl';
    }
    return '$_basePath/';
  }
}
```